# Multiprocessing in python with large argument list

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am new in python and struggling with multiprocessing. My machine has 8 CPU cores.
I have a list of numbers which need to be processed one by one. List length is 400.

```
list = [1, 2, 3...,400]
```

My function is like:

```
def abc():
   df1 = df1.query('xyz = list[0]') #Require multiprocessing here
   df2 = df2.query('efg = list[0]') #Require multiprocessing here
   result = do something with df1 and df2
   result.to_csv(file)
   print("result")
```

I don't know how to write the code which will distribute these 400 arguments between 8 CPU cores. Also each subprocess result will write to the same csv file.
How can this be achieved in python? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So is the multiprocessing needed to actually build your two dataframes? What exactly happens during the construction that requires multiprocessing? You may need to add some additional detail here

Comment: are you saying you want to call `abc` 400 times,  or your dataframe query? If the second- the dataframe implementation is already multi-threaded and set up to work around the GIL

Comment: `@Paul Becotte` yes, call abc 400 times so that the query statements get a new list element everytime, untill all list elements are exhausted.

Comment: `@C.Nivs` yes df1 and df2 will be build using multiprocessing. So df1 and df2 will contain different data everytime.

Comment: have a look at the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893635/returning-multiple-lists-from-pool-map-processes) & the answer on how to retrieve multiple lists, it might be of some help.

Comment: `@DrBwts` No it didnt help. Infact its written in the answer tht this question has nothing to do with multiprocessing. Its about unzipping lists.